# Laravel installation stops and php artisan commands aren't running

Tags: php, laravel

I've already added php to the path, also installed everything to setup a laravel project, but when i run `php artisan <command>` it just doesn't do anything. My current OS is Windows 10.

What is curious is that when creating a project i got a prompt message saying "CLI has stopped" and there project installation stops:

```
C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects>composer create-project laravel/laravel exam 5.0
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.0)
    Loading from cache

Created project in exam
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)

C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects>
```

I can run composer commands, but i cant run **php artisan**.

Also when running `composer update` the php artisan commands like optimize... aren't runned:

```
C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects\exam>composer install --prefer-dist
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)

C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects\exam>
```

Here's what i added to PATH (i'm using MAMP Pro):

`C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8;`

What could be happening?

Comment: Can you run `php -v` ?

Comment: Yes, here's the output: `PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: May 13 2015 22:19:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
`

Comment: Try running `php artisan test` and see if you get an error.

Comment: I cant run any artisan command: `C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects\exam>php artisan test

C:\Users\x\PhpstormProjects\exam>
`

Comment: I found my solution here: [issue#3604](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3604)